# how do I use the selector from the previous function?

Tags: javascript, selector, mouseover

I'm pretty new to JS and I'm working on a simple script that's displaying pictures, but also using a mouseOver function to enlarge them in a different target. This is what I've got so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
  a = '<a href="img/'
  b = '/pic';
  c = '.jpg" target=_blank><img src="img/'
  d = '/pic';
  e = '.jpg" height="100px" onMouseOver="mouseOver(';
  f = ');this.style.opacity=1" onMouseOut="this.style.opacity=0.9" style="opacity:0.9;"></a>';

  function printImage(x) {
    for (var i=0; i<=35; i++){
      document.write(a + x + b + i + c + x + d + i + e + i + f);
    }
  }

  function mouseOver(i){
    document.pic.src="img/refugeelive/pic"+i+".jpg";
  }
</script>
```

The `x` as the printImage selector is the name of the folder the pictures are in, right now that's refugeelive. How do I use that same `x` selector in the mouseOver function, so how do I replace `img/refugeelive/pic"+i+".jpg" by "img/"+x+"/pic"+i=".jpg`?

If there's a way to actually do this better, please tell me.

Comment: you could add `x` to your `mouseOver(i,x)` -function

Comment: `x` is still undefined then, tried to add it between the `i + f` part but didn't work.

Comment: yeah thats what I mean ...`e + i + ','+ x + f);` or so...and then add it in your function head and replace the link like in your example above

Comment: I did that, did not work.

Comment: any error in console output?

Comment: I don't know how to check that? Like I said I'm pretty new to JS so I don't know anything about console output..

Comment: oh ok ;) in chrome or firefox press F12 ....in chrome go to the console tab then reload your side and hover over the links, look out if something happens in the console

Comment: it gives this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: refugeelive is not defined

Comment: Thanks for helping, I tried some other things and figured it missed something, this was the solution:
`e + i + ','+ "'"+x+"'" + f);`
Thanks for the push in the right direction @lgoel

Answer (score 0):

I understood the following:

- several images should be displayed,
- if the user moves the mouse over one image this image should be diplayed bigger at another location.

If i misunderstood your requirements please leave a comment and i will try to update my sample accordingly.

You can take a look at **[my demo of the code below](http://plnkr.co/edit/qVMnSADYuKxeVVamTCw4?p=preview)**. By passing `this` you can get a reference to the element the mouse was moved over. So you do not need to store the selector somewhre.

Given this html

```
<a href="img/folder_1/A.png"><img src="img/folder_1/A.png" 
    onmouseover="viewImage(this);setStyle(this, 1);" 
    onmouseout="setStyle(this, 0.6);"/></a><br />

<a href="img/folder_2/rob.jpg"><img src="img/folder_2/rob.jpg" 
    onmouseover="viewImage(this);setStyle(this, 1);" 
    onmouseout="setStyle(this, 0.6);"  /></a><br />

<a href="img/folder_3/ram.jpg"><img src="img/folder_3/ram.jpg"
    onmouseover="viewImage(this);setStyle(this, 1);" 
    onmouseout="setStyle(this, 0.6);"  /></a>

<img id="previewImage" />
```

You can use this javscript:

```
function viewImage(that) {  
    var image = document.getElementById("previewImage");
    image.src = that.src;
    return true;
}

function setStyle(that, op) {
    that.style.opacity = op;
    return true;
}
```